# In vba, a "On Error GoTo" statement does not work. Compiler gives an error after the statement

Tags: excel, vba

Looping through excel files in a folder and trying to read from individual workbooks sheet named "result"

However, when a WB is opened that does not have said sheet, the compiler stops the script and gives an error.

When line `Set CurrentSheet = wbk.Sheets("result")`  gives an error it dos no go to `ErrorHandeling`. Why is that?

```vbs
 Function gg(path)
 
 Filename = Dir(path & "*.xl??")
 
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0
    DoEvents

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & Filename, False, True)   
 
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandeling
    Set CurrentSheet = wbk.Sheets("result")
    GoTo continuescript
ErrorHandeling:
    GoTo NextFile
continuescript:

NextFile:
    wbk.Close
    Filename = Dir
 Loop

 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

So this version works, but I still do not understand why the code in my question don't work.

```vbs
 Function gg(path)
 
 Filename = Dir(path & "*.xl??")
 
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0
    DoEvents

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & Filename, False, True)   
 
    On Error GoTo NextFile
    Set CurrentSheet = wbk.Sheets("result")
    ' does rest of the code here
NextFile:
    wbk.Close
    Filename = Dir
 Loop

 End Function
```

Comment: No, this should have the same problem.

Comment: That's strange, because it worked fine

Comment: Did you have more than one file that didn't have the sheet "result"?

Comment: ok, I actually deleted one of the files between testings. Now that I added the second file back to the folder I got the error again

Comment: Exactly. So change your `GoTo NextFile` to `Resume NextFile` (in the original code, not here) like suggested in the duplicate.